# VBA in Excel to Represent Access Is Null

Tags: ms-access-2010

So, my problem is with the Descripcheck Variable as I am passing data through Excel VBA to an Access database, each description is unique but the only problem is if I have a blank line how can I modify the below code to have IS NULL in it such that it looks like the second code snip it shown.

1. ```
   sCmndString = "SELECT * FROM " & tablename & " WHERE Description =" & _
                 " & Chr$(34) & Descripcheck & Chr$(34) & ";"
   ```

   2.

   ```
    sCmndString = "SELECT * FROM " & tablename & " WHERE Description IS NULL;
   ```

I assume I will have to have some modification if statement. I was just wondering if there was a really quick way of doing so. Now for expansion purposes lets assume that I now have description as a NUMBER instead of a string would I Handel it the same way, of course the Car$(34) would not be in the code line.

Comment: You can escape a double-quote character as two sequential quotes... so for example myStr="I said ""Yes.""" would produce 'I said "Yes."' when you print the string. No need to use Chr$(34)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do your conditional in the SQL itself:

```
sCmndString = "SELECT * FROM " & tablename & " WHERE Description =""" & _
              Descripcheck & """ OR Description IS NULL;"
```

As far as it being a "Number" you have to understand that 'Description' has a type in whatever table it is... if the type is a string, then it doesn't matter if Descripcheck is "5", it's still a string and thus would always need the quotes in the comparison.

Comment: No I mean if I Had a new statement string where the data type is a Number

Comment: Ok... then sure, you can use the same general SQL string just eliminating the quotes, that's correct.